# cloud computing in .net 4.0

Tags: .net, cloud, asp.net, c#

Since the launch of .net 4.0 the buzz word has been cloud computing. But very little is said and discussed about it in perspective of .net technologies. Further is it really the worth to invest or do we have sufficient current technologies that can handle what cloud computing offers ?

Can you please describe it and an example would be quite helpful !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud computing is another name for what a lot of us have been doing for a long time. Distributed computing and service oriented architecture. The tools are already there in your IDE and in your framework. Apply them with discretion and where necessary. Know the buzzwords, but don't pay them too much attention.

The main thing that has been added by the current discussions on cloud-based computing is the emphasis on being able to scale up quickly and pay for what you use. But again, from a technology point of view, this has been available to us for a long time.

Comment: So cloud computing in .net 4.0 does not offer anything new and all of it was already available ?

Comment: I'm not saying that .Net 4 adds nothing. I am saying that you don't have to use .Net 4.0 and Azure to produce a distributed, scalable, pay-per-use service. As some of the other answers show, there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in MS solution for cloud computing you can check [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/), [SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/) and [AppFabric](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/). About general info on cloud computing you can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

But mainly as Daniel mentioned technologies are almost the same. Even platforms almost the same... like IIS 7/WAS/ Biztalk Server/ Windows Server/ MS SQL Server, of course with a little modifications and even not for all of them.

Answer (score 3):

A cloud technology that would make specific use .net is [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/).

Cloud Computer is basically another form of [grid computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing) with the details of infrastructure abstracted away.

To make best use of cloud for custom apps you will need to be aware of the issue with concurrent and distributed systems eg Race Conditions, And you need to know how to transfer the data back and forth from the cloud.

Microsoft is not the only provider of cloud services:

Amazon is one with EC2 http://aws.amazon.com/

Amazon does have .net bindings http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forumindex.jspa

Google is another with it's app engine http://code.google.com/appengine/

Example Google apps http://appgallery.appspot.com/

Comment: Is Windows Azure now a standard product... i mean is it reliable and stable for one to invest in ?

Comment: I am not sure how mature is Windows Azure, but as I can see MS invests a lot in it.